# Android onLocationChanged (maxDistance)

Tags: android, gps

I have a tracking device using both network and gps as the provider.

However, sometimes the providers sends me a location that is way off mark. How can I solve this issue?

```
   // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;
```

Is there a parameter of some sort that ignores distance changes for updates > than a certain amount?

Open to any advice! Thanks

Comment: How do you configure `LocationRequest` to retrieve location update?

Comment: @Wizard are you asking for help or are you trying to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

How many updates are you checking for? If you're only checking for one update it could be returning the same value each time. If you are creating a location request using LocationRequest.create(), you can set the number of updates to be > 1 by using `request.setNumUpdates(int)` and then you can set a threshold in onLocationChanged to see if the returned location is less than a certain value.

Comment: I'm continuously checking for updates. This will sort of like a running app

Answer (score 0):

in my OnLocationChanged, I added a checker if location.distance < 300m, I would use the data. Any flaws to this?

Comment: 300m is a pretty far distance. If you are needing an accurate location I would suggest going far lower

Comment: @swerly thanks for your suggestion. I use 300m because it is hard to emulate (android studio) a change in distance for <300m